# add Map Zoom to this code ( gmap )

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

We use this script to show Gmap, but I cannot for the life of me remember who did it for us, what I do know is we need a Map Zoom added to it.. buggered if I know how.

The script is as follows:

```
var userLocation = '<?php echo $address; ?>';

if (GBrowserIsCompatible())
{
    var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
    geocoder.getLocations(userLocation, function (locations)
    {
        if (locations.Placemark)
        {
            var north = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.north;
            var south = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.south;
            var east = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.east;
            var west = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.west;
            var bounds = new GLatLngBounds(new GLatLng(south, west), new GLatLng(north, east));
            var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
            var Icon = new GIcon();
            Icon.image = "http://somesite.com/marker.png";
            Icon.iconSize = new GSize(33, 50);
            map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
            map.addOverlay(new GMarker(bounds.getCenter()), Icon);
        }
    });
}
```

The PHP actually grabs address from our dB and the map plots that location, which shouldn't have anything to do with the script.

Just need the zoom feature.

I have tried adding:

```
mapTypeControl: false,
zoomControl: true,
```

With no luck... I am a total gMap noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like Google Maps API version 2 code. Documentation can be found [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html).

```
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
// //// add this code \\\\
map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl3D());  // large pan+zoom control (3d)
// \\\\ add this code ////
var Icon = new GIcon();
```

You can use (and add) other controls as well. For example:

- `GSmallMapControl` -- compact version of pan+zoom control
- `GSmallZoomControl` -- compact version of zoom control
- `GScaleControl` -- adds scale information to the map
- `GMapTypeControl` -- map type chooser control (toggle b/w map, satellite, hybrid etc)

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to convert all code to GMAP3. Its going OK, but I am having issues with Map Markers Now.